# In IBM Websphere configured AD LDAP but logging in application only works with full DN

Tags: ldap, websphere

Trying to add AD LDAP authentication in IBM Websphere 9.0.0.7,
the login of application only works with full DN instead of sAmAccountName

No user xxx found

Answer (score 0):

We would need details on your configuration (wimconfig.xml) and possibly logs and trace to resolve this. If you have a support contract with IBM I would suggest opening a support case and we can help determine the issue.

You can open a case at the link below. We would require you upload your wimconfig.xml as well as trace that shows the issue (com.ibm.ws.wim.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.wim.*=all).

```
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport
```

Alternatively, you could post the wimconfig.xml file here and I can check for obvious issues, but without trace to see why it is failing it may be a shot in the dark.